# Failed assertion: line 20 pos 16: 'longitude != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm trying to build a TaxiApp where a passenger is supposed to search for a dropOff location but each time the user searches for a location and clicks on it using the **Google Autocomplete**  It keeps bringing this error: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/src/types/location.dart': Failed assertion: line 20 pos 16: 'longitude != null': is not true.

[image: This is the error displayed]

That error points to this method

```
Future<void> getPlaceDirection() async
  {
    var initialPos = Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).pickUpLocation;
    var finalPos = Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).dropOffLocation;

    var pickUpLatLng = LatLng(initialPos.latitude, initialPos.longitude);
    var dropOffLatLng = LatLng(finalPos.latitude, finalPos.longitude);

    showDialog(
      context: context, 
      builder: (BuildContext content) => ProgressDialog(message: "Please wait...",)
    );
    var details = await AssistantMethods.obtainPlaceDirectionDetails(pickUpLatLng, dropOffLatLng);
    setState(() {
          tripDirectionDetails = details;
        });

    Navigator.pop(context);

    print("This is the encoded points:: ");
    print(details.encodedPoints);

    PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();
    List<PointLatLng> decodedPolyLinePointsResult = polylinePoints.decodePolyline(details.encodedPoints);
    pLineCoordinates.clear();

    if (decodedPolyLinePointsResult.isNotEmpty)
    {
      decodedPolyLinePointsResult.forEach((PointLatLng pointLatLng)
      {
         pLineCoordinates.add(LatLng(pointLatLng.latitude, pointLatLng.longitude));
      });
    }

    polylineSet.clear();

    setState(() {
     Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      color: orange,
      polylineId: PolylineId("PolylineID"),
      jointType: JointType.round,
      points: pLineCoordinates,
      width: 5,
      startCap: Cap.roundCap,
      endCap: Cap.roundCap,
      geodesic: true,
       );

       polylineSet.add(polyline);
    });

    LatLngBounds latLngBounds;
      if(pickUpLatLng.latitude > dropOffLatLng.latitude && pickUpLatLng.longitude > dropOffLatLng.longitude)
      {
        latLngBounds = LatLngBounds(southwest: dropOffLatLng, northeast: pickUpLatLng);
      }
      else if(pickUpLatLng.longitude> dropOffLatLng.longitude)
      {
        latLngBounds = LatLngBounds(southwest: LatLng(pickUpLatLng.latitude, dropOffLatLng.longitude), 
        northeast: LatLng(dropOffLatLng.latitude, pickUpLatLng.longitude));
      }
      else if(pickUpLatLng.latitude > dropOffLatLng.latitude)
      {
        latLngBounds = LatLngBounds(southwest: LatLng(dropOffLatLng.latitude, pickUpLatLng.longitude), 
        northeast: LatLng(pickUpLatLng.latitude, dropOffLatLng.longitude));
      } 
      else 
      {
        latLngBounds = LatLngBounds(southwest: pickUpLatLng, northeast: dropOffLatLng);
      }

      newGoogleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 70));

      Marker pickUpLocMarker = Marker(
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueBlue),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: initialPos.placeName, snippet: "My location"),
        position:  pickUpLatLng,
        markerId: MarkerId("pickUpId"),
      );

      Marker dropOffLocMarker = Marker(
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: finalPos.placeName, snippet: "Drop-off location"),
        position:  dropOffLatLng,
        markerId: MarkerId("dropOffId"),
      );

      setState(() {
              markerSet.add(pickUpLocMarker);
              markerSet.add(dropOffLocMarker);
            });

      Circle pickUpLocCircle = Circle(
        fillColor: Colors.blue,
        center: pickUpLatLng,
        radius: 12,
        strokeWidth: 4,
        strokeColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        circleId: CircleId("pickUpId")
      );

      Circle dropOffLocCircle = Circle(
        fillColor: Colors.red,
        center: dropOffLatLng,
        radius: 12,
        strokeWidth: 4,
        strokeColor: Colors.redAccent,
        circleId: CircleId("dropOffId"),
      ); 

      setState(() {
              circleSet.add(pickUpLocCircle);
              circleSet.add(dropOffLocCircle);
            }); 
  }
```

Comment: check the answer , you havent added your main function but still tried to reflect it using pseudo code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Understanding The Problem**

You need to use `FutureBuilder` widget because your App depends on on waiting for another operation to complete. Otherwise latitude value will be **NULL**.

Check this - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

---

**Solution**

You must wrap your body of Scaffold (where you are actually calling the main map widget) with `FutureBuilder`. You haven't added the main function from where you are calling your map widget but the following is the pseudo-code to do it -

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        title: Text('Map'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
     //this mapWidget should be wrapped in future builder
      body: mapWidget(),
    );
  }

 Widget mapWidget() {
    return FutureBuilder(
                
                future: getPlaceDirection,//adding your main location widget in future
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state.connectionState == ConnectionState.active ||
                      state.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return SpinKitRipple(
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return DecoratedBox(
                               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                               color: index.isEven ? Colors.grey : 
                                    Color(0xffffb838),
                               ),);},);
                  } 
                  else {

//here you should write your main logic to be shown once latitude ! = NULL
               
                   }
}
```